# Describe in clear English a Turing machine that semidecides the following language.

Tags: logic, formal-languages, turing-machines

The language being L, which is described as follows:

$L$ = { $<M>$ | $M$ accepts the binary encodings of at least 4 odd numbers } .

---

I understand that this involves using one turing machine to simulate another. What sort of methodology could I use for these kinds of questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Describe a Turing machine that can:

1. generate the requested encodings
2. pass it to the original machine
3. stop if original machine would accept