# Describe in English a Turing machine that semidecides the following language - Is this solution correct?

Tags: logic, formal-languages, turing-machines

The language being L, which is described as follows:

$L$ = { $<M>$ | $M$ accepts the binary encodings of at least 4 odd numbers } .

My solution:

M generates the binary encodings in $\Sigma_M*$ in ascending order and uses dovetailing to interleave the computation of M on those binary encodings. As soon as four computations accept, M halts and accepts.

Is this correct? What corrections would have to be made if not? I am not sure if I am providing enough details in my solution which may cause it to be incorrect.

Comment: Seems fine to me. You might want to specify that by 'ascending order' you mean 'lexicographically increasing' (or something else). Oh and btw: You used $M$ to denote two different Turing machines. So you should fix that.

Comment: I understand the first part of your comment which is great, but I am not so sure about the second part. Am I actually referring to <M> in my solution? Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: I spelled out a little more details in my answer below. But honestly, your attempt is already pretty close. You should pay extra attention to the role of $M$ vs $N$ in my answer.

Comment: You previously asked a very similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2035463/14578.  If you ask two closely related questions, please link to the prior question so people are aware of its existence.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$
L = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid M \text{ accepts the binary code of at least } 4 \text{ odd numbers} \}
$$

Now construct a Turing machine $N$ such that

1. $N$, on input $I$, checks whether $I = \langle M \rangle$ for some Turing machine $M$. If not, stop and reject.
2. If $I = \langle M \rangle$ for some Turing machine $M$, $N$ runs $M$ on the binary codes of all odd numbers. More precisely, $N$ has two phases between which it alternates. During the first phase it writes down the least odd number that it hasn't run $M$ on yet (for at least one step). Then it runs $M$ on all numbers it has written down thus far for $1$ step (or any other finite number of steps). $N$ accepts $I$ if it passes our test in item 1. and $M$ accepts (at any point during $N$'s run) the binary code of $4$ odd numbers.

Comment: Note that item 1., for all $I$, stops after a finite number of steps. In other words: $L' = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid M \text{ is a Turing machine} \}$ is recursive. (However, for my approach to work, we only need that item 1. stops for actual codes of Turing machines after a finite number of steps.)

Comment: So this system that you described is decidable, rather than semi-decidable?

Comment: @AppreciateIt No, it's only semi-decidable - at least that's all I've proved. If $I = \langle M \rangle$ for some turing machine $M$ that doesn't accept the binary code of at least $4$ odd numbers, $N$ will never stop on input $I$.

Comment: Hint: You can actually prove that $L$ is not decidable, by reducing it to the halting problem.

Comment: Oh sh*t I understand now,! Thank you so much, semi-decidable means the machine could still explicitly reject right? Or must it always loop instead of halting if it rejects?

Comment: @AppreciateIt You're very welcome. Since you are new to MSE: If you are satisfied with my answer, you can decide to upvote and accept it. Once you accepted an answer to one of your questions, it will be marked as such which not only gives reputation to the author of the answer, but also helps the community to recognize this problem as solved.

Comment: @AppreciateIt Semi-decidable means that there is a Turing machine enumerating the given language $L$. Decidable means that both $L$ and its complement are semi-decidable. (Which is not the case in your example.)

Comment: Do semi-decidable machines ever halt and reject?

Comment: @AppreciateIt Yes, this is possible. In this case $N$ halts and rejects on any input that doesn't code a Turing machine. Note however that machines are not *semi-decidable* - languages are.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, and you are right Languages are semi-decidable. Oops